# Find finite structures $A_i$, $i\in I$ and an ultrafilter $U$ on $I$ so that the ultraproduct $\overset{}{\underset{i\in I}{\prod}} A_i/U$ is infinite

Tags: logic, model-theory

> Find finite structures $A_i$, $i\in I$ and an ultrafilter $U$ on $I$ so that the ultraproduct $\overset{}{\underset{i\in I}{\prod}} A_i/U$ is infinite.
> Hint: Take some really "simple" finite models $A_i$ that increases in size (say that $A_i$ is of size $i$) and a non-principal ultrafilter.

I am completely confused as to what to do. On my own, I can do nothing more than reciting definitions from the textbook. However, I saw that such a proposition exists:

> Let $L$ be a countable language, $(M_i:i\in \Bbb N)$ a sequence of $L$-structures and $U$ a non-principal ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$. Then the ultraproduct $\overset{}{\underset{i\in \Bbb N}{\prod}} M_i/U$ is $\aleph_1$-saturated.

Could anyone let me know if proving this proposition is the right direction to go?

(I apologise for the poor quality of this question; I know I am supposed to have at least given it a try, but I am so lost that I can do nothing but recite mindlessly the definitions in the book. I have never done any serious maths in university until now, so I am really desperate)

Comment: Try cyclic groups or prime fields..

Comment: @Berci I am sorry, but I have no idea what those are...

Comment: Hmm. What examples of structures are you familiar with, then?

Comment: @Berci I am not gonna lie, I am not familiar with any; I've worked with some really basic ones (e.g. $(\Bbb Z, s)$, $(\Bbb Q, <)$) in my assignments, but I wouldn't say I am familiar with them. As for advanced ones like groups or vector spaces, I know absolutely nothing...My background was in philosophy and economics, so I really don't know much about advanced maths concepts like these

Comment: Well, it's not a lucky situation then.. You have probably met addition of integers modulo a given positive number. Actually, these are the cyclic groups. Nevertheless, you can also do this exercise with sets without any structure.

Comment: are you familiar with [Łoś's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct#%C5%81o%C5%9B's_theorem)?

Comment: (as an aside; may I ask what the reference you are learning from is? it can be a bit cryptic to think about ultraproducts without having a store of examples to draw on, so it's generally best to have seen some other math – eg a bit of algebra – before tackling them. is this in the context of a course on logic?)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I've done an exercise that involves proving the compactness theorem with Łoś's theorem - 'done' in the sense that I read the proof elsewhere and wrote it in my own words, so in that sense I guess I am familiar with it?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom The course follows Hodges' Shorter Model Theory, but I personally like Marker's book more; basically I have never done any serious maths before (other than basic calculus), let alone different kinds of algebra. (My background is in econ and philos) I am currently doing a degree in logic, that is why I have been struggling sooo much with Model theory because I don't have any intuition of what's going on even after having looked at the examples (since examples are always made in reference to stuff like group/vector space...etc)...

Comment: one last question about this post, and then I'll write up an answer: do you know what principal and non-principal ultrafilters are? I am not surprised that the course might seem a bit arcane without some examples to draw on! and I am sorry you are struggling with it :/ ... perhaps would it be worth talking to your instructor and seeking their advice?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I haven't done anything on principal ultrafilter yet, but I did an exercise proving that a filter $D$ is principal iff $\bigcap D\in D$, so (I think) a principal filter is a filter with a minimum $\subseteq$ (i.e. $\bigcap D$). Extending on this, I think I should be able to grasp what a principal ultrafilter is...? (Instead of having a minimum $\subseteq$, it has a unique singleton?)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Yea...I've talked to him before and this is the 3rd time I've tried to pass Model theory so he knows I am struggling with it haha. And I thought category theory would be the worst of my nightmare...

Comment: Your approach can be used to solve the problem, yes, but it is akin to proving Tychonoff's theorem as a strategy for proving that the product topology is well-defined. It sounds to me like you're too deep in your own head, and you think that this is somehow something that is overly complicated and difficult, so it must be solved using some elaborate strategy. Take a breather, have a beer, some rest. Then notice that the hint is pretty much all you need to do, along with applying Łoś to sentences "There are at least $n$ distinct elements".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does it involve using the finite intersection property? Specifically, let $I$ be $\Bbb N$, then proving a set $W$ of subsets of $I$ satisfying the property would give us a non-principal ultrafilter...?

Comment: You really don't care about the actual ultrafilter, you just care that it's non-principal.